# which framework and language is used for built modern and complex web applicaton?

Tags: web-applications

I am almost beginner to web application platform. I want to built the complex web application for startup and i want fast result .So, for this which framework and langauge is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org) with [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is my personal go-to if I want something small really fast. [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) for some templating, [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for frontend.

You can also go for the old PHP/MySQL/Apache combo with [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/).

I'm sure everyone here will prove me wrong.

[Extremely long list of comparsions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks)

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar I sadly cannot delete an accepted answer.